# Error when I deploy a nuxt static app on css and js files urls

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I develop a Nuxt static app and I have a trouble when I generate the app. When I am using locally I don't have any problem with "npm run dev", but when I upload the code to the Amazon S3 bucket  or use "npm run start" in my routes load the incorrect url for the js and css files for example:
Locally for style.css file the app load "/css/style.css" this URL is correct but for another route I need the same url but the app create another url for the css or js files and don't found it, the incorrect url is for example "/xxxxxxx/css/style.css", Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

the app structure is:

```
/assets
/components
/css
/js
/images
/layouts
/pages
   /index.js -->"here doesn't have any problem"
   /preguntasFrecuentes.js  -->"Here is the problem"
/static
...
```

This is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost
    port: 3000, // default: 3000
  },
  components: true,
  head: {
    title: 'SirFunding',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0',
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: 'my website description',
      },
      { hid: 'X-UA-Compatible', content: 'IE=edge' },
      { name: 'facebook-domain-verification', content: 'm87opl945q79izhvirpbahxeb8qmbb' },
    ],
    link: [
      { href: 'css/bootstrap.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
      { href: 'css/style.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
      { href: 'css/responsive.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
      { href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Semi Condensed', rel: 'stylesheet' },
      { href: 'css/color-switcher-design.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
      { rel: 'shortcut icon', href: 'images/icono.png', type: 'image/x-icon' },
      { rel: 'icon', href: 'images/icono.png', type: 'image/x-icon' },
    ],
  },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/moment'],
}
```

and when I start the app with npm run start or upload in production the app looks like this:

[image: the image shows the app wihtout css and js files]

but when I start the app with npm run dev the app looks like this:

[image: the image show how should look whit css and js files]

the problem I found is when I build the app their paths for the css and js files are created incorrectly like this:

[image: the image in console part show the incorrect url for the css and js files]

in production o after to build the app adds in css or js files the name of the route in the url like this: http://192.168.0.15:3000/**preguntasFrecuentes**/js/color-settings.js or http://192.168.0.15:3000/**preguntasFrecuentes**/css/color-switcher-design.css and it is incorrect, the correct URL for both URLs are whitout **preguntasFrecuentes**.
I try moving the css and js files but this does not solve the problem

the `preguntasFrecuentes.vue` code is:

```html
<template>
  <div class="p-3 m-3 color_title1">
    <div class="p-2 col-sm-12 todos_text">
      <h2 class="text-center text-dark">Preguntas Frecuentes</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="text-justify col col-12">
        <div id="preguntasfrecuentesAccordion" class="accordion">
          <SectionsFaqCard v-for="faq in faqs" :key="faq.id" :faq="faq"> </SectionsFaqCard>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import faq from '~/static/FAQ.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      faqs: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.faqs = faq.FAQ
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code here. Hard to help by guessing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Usually, you do have `css` in assets. Also, try using `~/assets/css/style.css`

Comment: Can you show us the content of `preguntasFrecuentes`? Btw, it'd better if it'll be named `preguntas-frecuentes.vue` IMO.

Comment: it can't solve the problem

Comment: Please answer to my 2 previous comments.

Comment: Please make an effort in formatting when you do share a snippet of code.

Comment: I add this: ~/assets/css/style.css but can't solve the problem and I just add preguntasFrecuentes.vue code

Comment: Oh wait, I realized that you put it into a `link` in your `nuxt.config.js`? If you want some global style, you need to write it as `css: ['~/assets/css/style.css'],` in your `nuxt.config.js`. If you don't give it a proper prefix, it's legit that it freaks out because it just takes your current path and adds it what you're telling him to. I'm really not sure about all the other ones in `link` tho..

Comment: you shouldn't use links in the head for css, instead, you should add it to the layout or as a plugin or module so its bundled, also you really should use [nuxt-google-font](https://google-fonts.nuxtjs.org/) for the font, and perhaps nuxt [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#nuxt-js) module for bootsrap.. the issue is when you build css/ folder won't exist

Comment: I try your possible solutions but nothing changes, the problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment that I found the solution for this issue and it was very simple only I added "/" in nuxt.confing.js in link part in the begining of the url like this:

```js
export default {
    ...,
    link: [
       { href: '/css/bootstrap.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
       { href: '/css/style.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
       { href: '/css/responsive.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
       { href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Semi Condensed', rel: 'stylesheet' },
       { href: '/css/color-switcher-design.css', rel: 'stylesheet' },
       { rel: 'shortcut icon', href: 'images/icono.png', type: 'image/x-icon' },
    ],
  },
  ....
}
```

and for the js files I add the same '/' in the app.html file.

Comment: This is not a good solution even if it works, it is not how you're supposed to do it.